# calculating the mean of a list of timestamps ignoring weekend days in python

Tags: python, datetime, mean

I have a list of timestamps and I want to calculate the mean of the list, but I need to ignore the weekend days which are Saturday and Sunday and consider Friday and Monday as one day.  I only want to include the working days from Monday to Friday.  This is an example of the list. I wrote the timestamps in readable format to follow the process easily. 
Example:

['Wed Feb  17 12:57:40 2011', ' Wed Feb  8 12:57:40 2011', 'Tue Jan 25 17:15:35 2011']
MIN='Tue Jan 25 17:15:35 2011'

' Wed Feb  17 12:57:40 2011' , since we have 6 weekend days between this number and the MIN I shift back this number 6days.It will be  = 'Fri Feb 11  12:57:40 2011'.

'Wed Feb  8 12:57:40 2011', since we have 4 weekend days  between this number and the MIN I shift back this number 4days it will be  'Wed Feb  4 12:57:40 2011'

The new list is now [' Fri Feb 11  12:57:40 2011',' Wed Feb  4 12:57:40 2011',' Tue Jan 25 17:15:35 2011]

MAX= 'Fri Feb 11  12:57:40 2011'

average=   (Fri Feb 11  12:57:40 2011 + Wed Feb  4 12:57:40 2011 + Tue Jan 25 17:15:35 2011) /3

difference= MAX - average

Comment: How do you intend to caculate the "mean"?  That's usually `sum(elements)/number_of_elements`, but I'm not quite sure how you add times.

Comment: I can only guess it's some sort of associative array?

Comment: Also what have you tried so far.

Comment: jose Antonio, please edit question and say what you think the answer is for your given example.  Also supply an answer for this case: `days=['Fri Jan 14 12:12:12 2000',
 'Sat Jan 15 12:12:12 2000',
 'Sun Jan 16 12:12:12 2000',
 'Mon Jan 17 12:12:12 2000']

Comment: I converted the timestamps into epoch format and it is easy to calculate the mean=Sum/count. The the problem here it includes the weekend days.I want to exclude the weekend days during the mean calculation and consider Friday and Monday as 1 day

Comment: Show your results for the two examples.

Comment: So, for input ['Mon Dec 3 12:00:00 2012', 'Mon Dec 31 12:00:00 2012'] you would take the average of ['Mon Dec 3 12:00:00 2012', 'Thu Dec 27 12:00:00 2012'], which is Sat Dec 15 12:00:00 2012, and which is 12 days from 3 Dec and 16 from 31 Dec?

Comment: No, since we have 8 weekend days in between we shift  Mon Dec 24 12:00:00 2012 8 days before. The new list will be ['Mon Dec 3 12:00:00 2012', 'Thu Dec 24 12:00:00 2012']. We do our calculation on this list.

Comment: average(['Mon Dec 3 12:00:00 2012', 'Thu Dec 24 12:00:00 2012']) is 'Fri Dec 14 00:00:00 2012' which is 10.5 days from 3 Dec noon and 17.5 from 31 Dec noon, which does not resemble how an average should behave.  Eg average(['Mon Dec 10 12:00:00 2012', 'Fri Dec 14 12:00:00 2012']) is 'Wed Dec 12 12:00:00 2012' and averageBusinessDay(['Mon Dec 3 12:00:00 2012', 'Fri Dec 21 12:00:00 2012']) should be the same, but you compute it as average(['Mon Dec 3 12:00:00 2012', 'Mon Dec 17 12:00:00 2012']), which is two days earlier.  Adding a week at each end shouldn't change value, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Edit:* [Removed previous code, which had an error; replaced with code below.]

Here is some output from code that squeezes out weekends, computes average, and puts weekends back in to get an apparently valid average.  The code is shown after the output from some test cases.

```
['Fri Jan 13 12:00:00 2012', 'Mon Jan 16 11:00:00 2012']
Average =  Fri Jan 13 23:30:00 2012
['Fri Jan 13 12:00:00 2012', 'Mon Jan 16 13:00:00 2012']
Average =  Mon Jan 16 00:30:00 2012
['Fri Jan 13 14:17:58 2012', 'Sat Jan 14 1:2:3 2012', 'Sun Jan 15 4:5:6 2012', 'Mon Jan 16 11:03:29 2012', 'Wed Jan 18 14:27:17 2012', 'Mon Jan 23 10:02:12 2012', 'Mon Jan 30 10:02:12 2012']
Average =  Thu Jan 19 16:46:37 2012
['Fri Jan 14 14:17:58 2011', 'Mon Jan 17 11:03:29 2011', 'Wed Jan 19 14:27:17 2011', 'Mon Jan 24 10:02:12 2011']
Average =  Wed Jan 19 00:27:44 2011
```

Python code:

```
from time import strptime, mktime, localtime, asctime
from math import floor

def averageBusinessDay (dates):
    f = [mktime(strptime(x)) for x in dates]
    h = [x for x in f if localtime(x).tm_wday < 5]  # Get rid of weekend days
    bweek, cweek, dweek = 3600*24*5, 3600*24*7, 3600*24*2    
    e = localtime(h[0])  # Get struct_time for first item
    # fm is first Monday in local time
    fm = mktime((e.tm_year, e.tm_mon, e.tm_mday-e.tm_wday, 0,0,0,0,0,0))
    i = [x-fm for x in h]  # Subtract leading Monday
    j = [x-floor(x/cweek)*dweek for x in i]  # Squeeze out weekends
    avx = sum(j)/len(j)
    avt = asctime(localtime(avx+floor(avx/bweek)*dweek+fm))
    return avt

def atest(dates):
    print dates
    print 'Average = ', averageBusinessDay (dates)

atest(['Fri Jan 13 12:00:00 2012', 'Mon Jan 16 11:00:00 2012'])
atest(['Fri Jan 13 12:00:00 2012', 'Mon Jan 16 13:00:00 2012'])
atest(['Fri Jan 13 14:17:58 2012', 'Sat Jan 14 1:2:3 2012', 'Sun Jan 15 4:5:6 2012', 'Mon Jan 16 11:03:29 2012', 'Wed Jan 18 14:27:17 2012', 'Mon Jan 23 10:02:12 2012', 'Mon Jan 30 10:02:12 2012'])
atest(['Fri Jan 14 14:17:58 2011', 'Mon Jan 17 11:03:29 2011', 'Wed Jan 19 14:27:17 2011', 'Mon Jan 24 10:02:12 2011'])
```

Comment: Thank you very very much. It was very helpful with me. But still I am facing the same problem with weekends.Is there any way to consider the interval from Friday midnight to Sunday midnight as being of zero length. This is what I really want. Thank you very much again and I am looking forward to  receive  from you useful hints on how to do that.

Comment: Replaced old code with new code to squeeze out weekends, compute average, and put weekends back in

Comment: Many thanks for you, It is an excellent job you are very professional it is very hard coded with respect to my knowledge. But, when I tried to test it using several examples I see something strange in the output. Does the code ignore weekends during the calculation when I have several weeks, like this example ['Thu Dec  1 09:02:00 2011', 'Tue Dec 20 09:45:56 2011']. When I took the max here and subtract it from the average take from your code the output should be smaller than when including weekends but I see the opposite output. If I am missing something please correct me

Comment: For that input it shows 'Fri Dec  9 21:23:58 2011' which I regard as right.  For a simpler case, averageBusinessDay (['Thu Dec 1 00:00:00 2011', 'Tue Dec 20 00:00:00 2011']) for a total included time range of 13 business days shows 'Fri Dec  9 12:00:00 2011', which is 6.5 business days from either end.  What value do you think it should be?

Comment: I am a little bit confused. Therefore, I tried to apply  the code to the whole file to see the result. But I receive the following error  mean=averageBusinessDay(m3) 
  File "test.py", line 33, in averageBusinessDay
    avx = sum(j)/len(j)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

Comment: I don't know how to reproduce that error and don't know what's in m3.  Note, averageBusinessDay() as shown in question expects a list of strings, one date per string.  You could revise it to accept a list of dates in seconds-of-epoch format.  As is, a seconds-list would give “TypeError: expected string or buffer” so I expect that's not the problem.  You could add the following before the avx=... line: `print 'j',j`.  Also, does your code have any variables called sum or len?

Comment: You are right I have a another variable called sum in the program. I fixed it but sorry I have received the following error File "overlapping2.py", line 85, in <module>
    mean=averageBusinessDay(m3) 
  File "overlapping2.py", line 28, in averageBusinessDay
    e = localtime(h[0])  # Get struct_time for first item
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: That IndexError: list index out of range would result if h is empty, ie if all the `dates` items are weekend days.  Before the `e = localtime(h[0])` line you could add the line `if not h: return None`

Comment: Thank you very much. It is working now but when I try to subtract the MAX -avt. I have received an error TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'str'. I know what is the problem but MAX are in float number in EPOCH format and avt is readable format. How can I convert them to be consistent in order to subtract them

Comment: avt to epoch seconds is mktime(strptime(avt)).  Also, in averageBusinessDay the expression avx+floor(avx/bweek)*dweek+fm is in epoch seconds so if you wanted to return epoch seconds return that instead of asctime(localtime()) of it

Comment: Many Many thanks for your patience with me. Now, I have the results but as I told you I am worried about the results. I compared the results of (MAX-average) before and after ignoring weekends. It is supposed to be smaller especially,  when having  long period that contains several weekends. Example 'Wed Feb  2 12:57:40 2011', 'Tue Jan 25 17:15:35 2011'  -- MAX-average= 117hours, while before ignoring the weekends period the value was smaller than this which is 93hours. I need your opinion please.

Again I appreciate your help.

Comment: I understand where is the problem.  [1294475637.0, 1294993722.0]  |  ['Sat Jan  8 09:33:57 2011', 'Fri Jan 14 09:28:42 2011']. In this example your code  firstly deletes any timestamps happed on Sat or Sun and then calculates the average its the same in this example as the 2nd item.So the MAX-average here will be 0.0. I want to keep all timestamps and delete any weekend periods in between and then calculate the average. I want to consider Friday and Monday and any timestamps in between as one day.

Comment: If that is what you want, add to the question more examples and details of their answers, and a formula.  Eg instead of just saying MAX-average= 117hours specifically say the exact value of MAX and the exact value of the average.  Include some examples with minutes and seconds equal to zero to make things more obvious.  Also, please vote up my answer.

Comment: I edited the question adding a detailed example. I hope you will get the idea and what I want exactly. Thank you

Comment: Dear jwpat7. I am still waiting  your answer if you are still interesting to help me. Thank you and I appreciate this from you since I am stucking on this problem.

Comment: See my recent comment to question.  You can adjust code by halving or dropping the `+floor(avx/bweek)*dweek` term.  Also, please vote up my answer: click the little up-pointing triangle above the big 0 (zero, nada, nothing) that is the count so far of upvotes for my answer.

Comment: What I want exactly is as follows: example [ ‘Mon Dec 3 12:00:00 2012', ' Fri Dec 7 12:00:00 2012] the average is “Wed Dec 5 12:00:00 2012” and should be the same as this case [‘Mon Dec 3 12:00:00 2012', ' Mon Dec 10 12:00:00 2012‘]. Because Mon and Fri should be considered as one day and the interval between them is of 0 time length. In your code, in the first case the average is  Mon Dec 3 12:00:00 2012, but in the second case is  “Thu Dec  6 00:00:00 2012” and this is different of the aforementioned result. Does your code consider this period of time as of 0 length?

Comment: With respect to voting, I am new to this site, when I pressed to vote  it appeared a message saying that “voting up requires 15 reputation” . Can you please guide me how to handle this issue?

Comment: A couple more question upvotes, or an answer upvote, or having an answer accepted, would increase your reputation above the 15 required to vote.  (I knew there was a minimum for voting, but had the mistaken notion it didn't apply for your own question.  Sorry for the hassle!)

Comment: Re wanting [ ‘Mon Dec 3 12:00:00 2012', ' Fri Dec 7 12:00:00 2012] and [‘Mon Dec 3 12:00:00 2012', ' Mon Dec 10 12:00:00 2012‘] to have same result, that doesn't make sense.  The latter should give half a day more.  Anyway, as noted above, adjust code by halving or dropping the +floor(avx/bweek)*dweek term to drop half or all of included weekend days.  I'd also add `sorted()` in first function line, ie change to `f = sorted([mktime(strptime(x)) for x in dates])`

Comment: I have updated the code according to your last comment. But, I see something strange. When I entered ‘Mon Dec 3 12:00:00 2012', ' Fri Dec 7 12:00:00 2012]. It supposed to give me "Wed  Dec 5 12:00:00 2012". I t gave me date 1970 something like this. Could you please test the code after you modify it?

Comment: Add some print statements and print the values of all the variables in the calculation, the values of some terms, etc.  Epoch second 0 is 1 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC or thereabouts so you probably left out or misplaced a parenthesis pair

Answer (score -1):

Split the strings based on ' ', take the first element and if it's not saturday or sunday, it's a weekday. Now I need to know what you mean by the "mean" of a list of dates.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply. I need to calculate the middle point which is equal to the sum divide by count

Comment: I converted the timestamps into epoch format and it is easy to calculate the mean=Sum/count. The the problem here it includes the weekend days.I want to exclude the weekend days during the mean calculation and consider Friday and Monday as 1 day